# payment card industry details

Tags: credit-card

I have a site with CC processing. Do i need any standards followed? Whats with payment card industry? Is that checks our site CC processing standards? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally yes, you have to comply with the PCI DSS (Payment Card Industry Data Security Standards).

More information is here: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/index.php